# World Wide Web Publishing Service stops after IISReset

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

There is an automated task on our web server that performs an IISReset /noforce every night.

For the second time today (in over a month) the World Wide Web Publishing Service stopped after the IISReset. The websites obviously didn't run after that.

I had no problems restarting the service this morning and the websites were started without problems right after that.

The World Wide Web Publishing Service is set to "restart the service" upon failure (first, second and subsequent). I can see the IISReset in the event log, but nothing about that service stopping (or failing to restart).

The server is running windows server 2008 / IIS 7.0

There are a few app pools running on the IIS instance (some standard ASP.NET web apps and WSS 3.0 SP2)

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Also, I just noticed that the SMTP service (which runs on IIS 6.0 and not IIS 7.0 like the rest of the app pools) had also stopped after the IISRESET /noforce from last night. Once again, nothing in the log...

Comment: I'm having he same issue. Is iisreset really going to fix it? The World Wide Web Publishing Service service is marked as an interactive service. However, the system is configured to not allow interactive services. This service may not function properly. How do I allow an interactive service? I have interactive service detection enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WSS or MOSS on IIS and when we do IISRESET /noforce.. sometimes IISRESET does not completes and leave the service in an unhealthy state. Restart the service upon failure will trigger when there is a failure in reset.. 
 I would be interested to know if the IISRESET event you see in the Event log is for the task configured or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am positive that the IISRESET event in the log is from the task configured. The task runs at 3:30 AM (windows task schedule + batch file) and this is exactly when the IISRESET appears in the log. If the IISRESET fails, does it leave anything in the log?

Comment: It can leave W3SVC service either in Stopping or Starting phase.. i.e. not started completely nor stopped completely.

Comment: Removed the IISReset and I now do an App Pool recycle instead. Problem seems to be fixed...